# How can I add custom message/img/gif upon hovering over certain texts in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have noticed that VS Code gives some additional information or links upon hovering over certain texts !!..
[Like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gddp7.png)
How can I do the same thing just with my own custom img/message/gif etc?

Comment: but what is the text you are hovering over, you can write a `HoverProvider` but when to supply a hover item